# Is it possible to inline LESS stylesheets?

Tags: css, less

For example, is it possible to do something like:

```
<style type="text/less">
  #foo {
    .bar {
       font-weight: bold;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: did you achieve something? I'm looking for the same

Comment: I did eventually bang out something that involved grabbing the contents of the style tag, parsing it, then injecting that… But it wasn't very nice, and couldn't reference definitions from the “main” less.css.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This has been possible since July 2010, and it works with today's Less 1.2.0 version.

See the [initial diff that added support for this](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/commit/45592cb3cc6c71c4ab493436139f8d1c51e61087).

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer, but definitely look below at Otto's answer too, because if you copy the OP's code, it definitely won't work.

Answer (score 87):

You actually need to use

```
<style type="text/less">
```

instead of:

```
<style type="stylesheet/less">
```

Otherwise it won't work.

Remember to place the `<style>` element before the `<script>` element to load less.js.

Comment: place the <style> element before the <script> element to load less.js.

Comment: I don't understand why they use stylesheet/less for the `<link>` tags in the first place.  the link's relation isn't different, it's the type of the referred page, ya' know?  why don't they have `<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css>`

Comment: @haxxerz probably has to do with not wanting the browser to mistakenly render the LESS code as CSS. By using rel=stylesheet/less, most browsers will ignore it as invalid

Comment: what if this is done dynamically, later ? window.less.sheets.push(element) only works if href is set ...

Comment: @jibsales, @haxxerz: According to [the spec](http://w3c.github.io/html/links.html#link-type-stylesheet), they should ignore it unless its type resolves to `text/css`. There has been discussion in [this `less.js` issue](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2521) about changing how browser embedding works.

Comment: you can call     less.refresh(); if you need to reload the inline less stylesheets