# Is there a way of using LESS inside the <style> element?

Tags: html, css, less, polymer, web-component

I'm experimenting with Polymer and want to be able to use LESS inside the `<style>` tag. So I'd want to be able do something like the following:

```
<style>
    my-component {
       color: @primary;
       .align-mid();
    }
</style>
```

(For me, a big benefit of web components is being able to package the mark up and styling together in one file so using a separate LESS stylesheet is not ideal.)

Comment: Nope, you will have to compile LESS to CSS before use

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping there's something out there that can compile LESS to CSS within the `<style>` tag.

Comment: It would be nice if support was added but I think that more CSS standardisation needs to come first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to inline LESS stylesheets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731702/is-it-possible-to-inline-less-stylesheets) (they don't seem to mention it, but you'll need [less.js](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser))

Comment: Can't you compile a HTML file as if it were LESS, and keep everything that the LESS compiler doesn't recognise unchanged?

Comment: @MrLister No, since Less compilers have to parse it and they obviously can't parse XML w/o special hacks (too dirty). For this use-case I'd suggest to look for some HTML preprocessor that can inject external files into HTML itself.

Comment: @Mr Lister: The LESS compiler would just see a garbled mess and possibly even misinterpret certain HTML fragments as valid LESS. It's the same reason why browsers don't even so much as try to remove wayward <style></style> tags from the beginning and end of a CSS file - all they see in those two tags is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. See
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9710229/4912760. And also http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage. You'll need to get and use the less.js script in your page. And then you'll need to set the type attribute of your style tags to 'text/less'.

Comment: Indeed, this will work if we consider only "I'm experimenting with Polymer". (But a warning to avoid this method for a production sites whenever possible is unavoidable).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using less inside a style element, I would recommend you have an external stylesheet that you link to.

So `foo.less`, which compiles down to `foo.css`. Then in your element you would link to `foo.css`.

`<link rel="import" type="css" href="foo.css">`

Here's an explanation: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#external-stylesheets